# VSC suddenly highlighting every word

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code (v1.63.2) suddenly highlights every word I have my selection on, how do I turn this off? It's really annoying.

[image: Highlighting all words with the same chars in VS code]

It doesn't matter if its a tag or a word, it will highlight every duplicate.

Comment: that is default behavior of VSC, you mist have disabled it and now toggled it back on, search the settings for stuff like `highlight`

Comment: `Editor: Selection Highlight`  or `Editor: Occurrences Highlight` depending on whether you really have the word selected or it is just where the cursor is.  You can also theme those in `colorCustomizations` to tone them down.